# Properties in Spring Environment

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-4

I'm trying to create a custom property placeholder.

At my Spring Configuration Class I have this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigurationClass2.class)
public class ConfigurationClass1 {
    @Bean
    @Lazy(false)
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer settings() throws IOException {
         // custom load of my properties file
         // legacy configuration, comes from a SVN repository
         // I need to download it and then do some logic and finally 
         // load it.
    }
}
```

At another configuration class I want to access some properties using the `Environment`, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ConfigurationClass2 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        String jdbcUrl = env.getProperty('jdbc.url');
        .... // jdbcUrl is null!!!!
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cronExpression}")
    public void worker() {
    } 

}
```

I don't want to use `@Value` or `@PropertySource`.

I need to load this properties manually and access this values programmatically!

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is wrong with using `@PropertySource` that is basically the same as loading it yourself, also it is mandatory if you want to use the `Environment` to access your properties. If you don't they are only known to your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and nothing else.

Comment: M. Deinum take a look at the changes of the post... this will explain why I cannot use @PropertySource

Comment: Create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which does the loading of the properties and adds `PropertySource` to the `Environment`. That way they are accesible through the `Environment` and the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` still works as well.

Comment: M. Deinum, how can I use this ApplicationContextInitializer when I'm not using web.xml but using the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ?

Comment: You can override the `customizeRegistration` and add an init parameter with the name `contextInitializerClasses` to specify the `ApplicationContextInitializer` to use.

Comment: M. Deinum, this did not worked. The ApplicationContextInitializer is called after Configuration classes. I need to read the properties before, to use them in the Configuration class via Environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65701/discussion-between-beto-neto-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Then you did something wrong as they are really read before that. I made the assumption that the classes were read by the `DispatcherServlet` but they are probably read by the `ContextLoaderListener`. If that is the case then override the `onStartup` method register the same init parameter there and call `super.onStartup` afterwards. You can then of course remove the the overridden `customizeRegistration` method.